# working with custom views and sqlite database-android

Tags: android

I m working on password manager app.
in which I have created database with one table.

`table_name` : `entry`

`fileds` : `id, title, category, username, password, website, comment`.

And the main activity contains views for above fields.
but now I want to add a button called `"add filed"` through which user can add new view like one more username , or edittext for any other custom entry.

But the problem is...

How can I save those custom entries into database? Because, there may be a possibility that user want to add one custom entry for first password. and two custom entries for second password. so how can I manage those extra custom records into database.

plz help..

Comment: have you problem with database that how to manage that extra field in sqlite?

Comment: yes exactly, i dont know how to manage diff no.s of extra fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Alter Table query to add new field in table.
For ex.,

```
 if (!isColumnExistInTableOrNot("entry", "username2" )) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE entry ADD COLUMN username2 varchar");

        }
```

the isColumnExistInTableOrNot() is.

```
 public static boolean isColumnExistInTableOrNot(SQLiteDatabase db,String tableName,
                                                    String ColumnName) {
        String Query = "select " + ColumnName + " from " + tableName;
        try {
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
            if (c != null) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i will try it.but one more question please.suppose, the one record in the table is as

Comment: contains 2 extra fields and second containd 4. then will it work? (in same table) will it effect other records?

Comment: not an issue.if you add one more column and update that one already exist record .set new column field value in exist record .

Comment: and can i add new column . ex username if its already exist.means duplicate name of column?

Comment: ok.i got it. the duplicate column name will give error. but your answer works for me. thanx @diplai

Comment: no if you wish then u can set value in newly added field .it will no effect in other records